# Delete everything that is not contained in a regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have the following list:

```
"tag": "test",
"id": "test-demo",
"name": "paid",
"domain_url": "http://example.com",
"in_range": [{
"range": "example.com",
"range_type": "website"
"range": "example.com",
"range_type": "website"
"range": "example.com",
"srange_type": "website"
"range": "example.com",
"range_type": "website"
```

I would like to use NOTEPAD++ to filter all the lines except what contains "domain_url" and "range".
I created the following regex:

```
"domain_url.*".*"|"range.*".*"
```

How can I delete everything except what the regex contains?
So the output of the list will be like this:

```
"domain_url": "http://example.com",
"range": "example.com",
"range": "example.com",
"range": "example.com",
"range": "example.com",
```

Answer (score 4):

You might use

```
^"(?!(?:domain_url|range)").*\R?
```

- `^` Start of string
- `"` Match a double quote
- `(?!(?:domain_url|range)")` Assert not either *domain_url"* or *range"*
- `.*\R?` Match the whole line and an optional newline

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JMFZlA/1).

[image]

Comment: ++ here. For `.*\R? Match the whole line and an optional newline` putting a `\n` OR `\r?\n` will also work here? Just asking

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Yes that will also work, but we can use `\R` as it can match a bit more as well, see https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html#whitespace regex101 explains it as `matches any Unicode newline sequence`

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Here is a more extensive explanation https://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcrepattern.html#newlineseq

Answer (score 1):

"Mark"ing the lines then using the "Bookmark" submenu gives ways to do this.

Firstly: Mark all lines containing the RegEx. Use menu => **Search** => **Mark** to open the "Mark" tab of the Find and replace dialogue, enter `"domain_url"|"range"` into the "Find what", ensure "Bookmark line" and "Regular expression" are selected. (This RegEx matches the description rather than the quoted Regex. There seem to be a mismatch with the double quotes (`"`) and full stops (`.`).) After clicking on "Mark all" expect to see blue blobs at the left of all wanted lines.

Two routes are now useful. Knowing both allows more options for future needs.

Either: Use menu => **Search** => **Bookmark** => **Remove non-bookmarked lines**.

OR: Invert the bookmarks using menu => **Search** => **Bookmark** => **Inverse bookmarks** then use menu => **Search** => **Bookmark** => **Remove bookmarked lines**.